# Create new column in R yes/no based off another column

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column in R (yes/no indicator) where if the data in X3 is >= 50 it would = 1(yes) or if <= 49 it would = 0(no).

I have tried various combinations of ifelse statements, I just cannot get it work. I need this step in order to construct my confidence interval.

> dput (crime)
>   structure(list(Y = c(478L, 494L, 643L, 341L, 773L, 603L, 484L, 
>   546L, 424L, 548L, 506L, 819L, 541L, 491L, 514L, 371L, 457L, 437L, 
>   570L, 432L, 619L, 357L, 623L, 547L, 792L, 799L, 439L, 867L, 912L, 
>   462L, 859L, 805L, 652L, 776L, 919L, 732L, 657L, 1419L, 989L, 
>   821L, 1740L, 815L, 760L, 936L, 863L, 783L, 715L, 1504L, 1324L, 
>   940L), X1 = c(184L, 213L, 347L, 565L, 327L, 260L, 325L, 102L, 
>   38L, 226L, 137L, 369L, 109L, 809L, 29L, 245L, 118L, 148L, 387L, 
>   98L, 608L, 218L, 254L, 697L, 827L, 693L, 448L, 942L, 1017L, 216L, 
>   673L, 989L, 630L, 404L, 692L, 1517L, 879L, 631L, 1375L, 1139L, 
>   3545L, 706L, 451L, 433L, 601L, 1024L, 457L, 1441L, 1022L, 1244L
>   ), X2 = c(40L, 32L, 57L, 31L, 67L, 25L, 34L, 33L, 36L, 31L, 35L, 
>   30L, 44L, 32L, 30L, 16L, 29L, 36L, 30L, 23L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 44L, 
>   28L, 35L, 31L, 39L, 27L, 36L, 38L, 46L, 29L, 32L, 39L, 44L, 33L, 
>   43L, 22L, 30L, 86L, 30L, 32L, 43L, 20L, 55L, 44L, 37L, 82L, 66L
>   ), X3 = c(74L, 72L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 68L, 68L, 62L, 69L, 66L, 60L, 
>   81L, 66L, 67L, 65L, 64L, 64L, 62L, 59L, 56L, 46L, 54L, 54L, 45L, 
>   57L, 57L, 61L, 52L, 44L, 43L, 48L, 57L, 47L, 50L, 48L, 49L, 72L, 
>   59L, 49L, 54L, 62L, 47L, 45L, 48L, 69L, 42L, 49L, 57L, 72L, 67L
>   ), X4 = c(11L, 11L, 18L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 
>   4L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 15L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 
>   12L, 9L, 19L, 17L, 21L, 18L, 19L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 
>   14L, 9L, 13L, 22L, 17L, 34L, 26L, 23L, 23L, 18L, 15L, 22L, 26L
>   ), X5 = c(31L, 43L, 16L, 25L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 28L, 25L, 58L, 21L, 
>   77L, 37L, 37L, 35L, 42L, 21L, 81L, 31L, 50L, 24L, 27L, 22L, 18L, 
>   23L, 60L, 14L, 31L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 21L, 32L, 31L, 13L, 
>   21L, 46L, 27L, 18L, 39L, 15L, 23L, 7L, 23L, 30L, 35L, 15L, 18L
>   ), X6 = c(20L, 18L, 16L, 19L, 24L, 15L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 9L, 
>   36L, 12L, 16L, 11L, 14L, 10L, 27L, 16L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 
>   11L, 18L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 22L, 
>   13L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 16L
>   ), X7 = structure(list(Y = c(478L, 494L, 643L, 341L, 773L, 603L, 
>   484L, 546L, 424L, 548L, 506L, 819L, 541L, 491L, 514L, 371L, 457L, 
>   437L, 570L, 432L, 619L, 357L, 623L, 547L, 792L, 799L, 439L, 867L, 
>   912L, 462L, 859L, 805L, 652L, 776L, 919L, 732L, 657L, 1419L, 
>   989L, 821L, 1740L, 815L, 760L, 936L, 863L, 783L, 715L, 1504L, 
>   1324L, 940L), X1 = c(184L, 213L, 347L, 565L, 327L, 260L, 325L, 
>   102L, 38L, 226L, 137L, 369L, 109L, 809L, 29L, 245L, 118L, 148L, 
>   387L, 98L, 608L, 218L, 254L, 697L, 827L, 693L, 448L, 942L, 1017L, 
>   216L, 673L, 989L, 630L, 404L, 692L, 1517L, 879L, 631L, 1375L, 
>   1139L, 3545L, 706L, 451L, 433L, 601L, 1024L, 457L, 1441L, 1022L, 
>   1244L), X2 = c(40L, 32L, 57L, 31L, 67L, 25L, 34L, 33L, 36L, 31L, 
>   35L, 30L, 44L, 32L, 30L, 16L, 29L, 36L, 30L, 23L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 
>   44L, 28L, 35L, 31L, 39L, 27L, 36L, 38L, 46L, 29L, 32L, 39L, 44L, 
>   33L, 43L, 22L, 30L, 86L, 30L, 32L, 43L, 20L, 55L, 44L, 37L, 82L, 
>   66L), X3 = c(74L, 72L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 68L, 68L, 62L, 69L, 66L, 
>   60L, 81L, 66L, 67L, 65L, 64L, 64L, 62L, 59L, 56L, 46L, 54L, 54L, 
>   45L, 57L, 57L, 61L, 52L, 44L, 43L, 48L, 57L, 47L, 50L, 48L, 49L, 
>   72L, 59L, 49L, 54L, 62L, 47L, 45L, 48L, 69L, 42L, 49L, 57L, 72L, 
>   67L), X4 = c(11L, 11L, 18L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 
>   4L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 15L, 15L, 22L, 14L, 20L, 26L, 
>   12L, 9L, 19L, 17L, 21L, 18L, 19L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 
>   14L, 9L, 13L, 22L, 17L, 34L, 26L, 23L, 23L, 18L, 15L, 22L, 26L
>   ), X5 = c(31L, 43L, 16L, 25L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 28L, 25L, 58L, 21L, 
>   77L, 37L, 37L, 35L, 42L, 21L, 81L, 31L, 50L, 24L, 27L, 22L, 18L, 
>   23L, 60L, 14L, 31L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 21L, 32L, 31L, 13L, 
>   21L, 46L, 27L, 18L, 39L, 15L, 23L, 7L, 23L, 30L, 35L, 15L, 18L
>   ), X6 = c(20L, 18L, 16L, 19L, 24L, 15L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 9L, 
>   36L, 12L, 16L, 11L, 14L, 10L, 27L, 16L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 
>   11L, 18L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 22L, 
>   13L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 16L
>   ), X7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .Names = c("Y", 
>   "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7"), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Y", 
>   "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7"), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -50L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: `dput` output doesn't seem to work. Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: What have you tried? This seems to work fine: `crime$myNewColumn <- ifelse(crime$X3 >= 50, 1, 0)`

Comment: This worked, thank you for being so kind and answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dput didn't work. But I'd managed to dump the data from column Y and X3 in a dataset (called `data`) and use `dplyr::mutate` to do the transformation with a straightforward `ifelse` condition.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% mutate(X3_cat = ifelse(X3 >= 50, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Please avoid answering obvious duplicate posts.

Comment: I am a novice and looked at other supposed duplicate posts and they did not make sense to me. Sometimes, people need some added help. Instead, maybe offer some help or point someone in a better direction before marking it as a duplicate.